# How do I set the date of a calendar view from another view using Jquery FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have 2 Jquery fullcalendar controls on my page.

I want to be able to click on a day on the 1st calendar which is in 'month mode', and then set the 2nd calendar which is by default using the AgengaDay view, to the day that has been clicked on the 1st calendar?

I've tried the following:

```
 $('#firstCalendar').fullCalendar({

            dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

                $('#secondcalendary').fullCalendar('select', date, date, allDay);
            }
 });
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Nice one- give me a while to try and sort it out. This is a good one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go--- Its not that difficult actually. Click on the Cal1 day and the Cal2 Changes!

http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/A56LN/

---

**CODE**

---

```
$('#mycalendar1').fullCalendar(
{
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    dayClick: function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ) {
        dayClicked(date);
    },
    events: [                         
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2011-03-10',
            end    : '2011-07-25'
        }
    ]
}); 


$('#mycalendar2').fullCalendar(
            {
             header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },

                defaultView: 'agendaDay',

                events: [                         
                        {
                            title  : 'event2',
                            start  : '2011-03-10',
                            end    : '2011-07-25'
                        }
                    ]
           }); 


function dayClicked(date){
    $('#mycalendar2').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date );
}
```

---

### Clicking the "TODAY" and other buttons..

<strike>I got some code like this. but this is not the solution. because it shows the date before the calendar changes. so basically the old date- maybe you can use a time-out? 500ms? or something - because jquery binds before the fullcalendar...</strike>

```
$('.fc-button-today').click(function() { 
     alert($('#mycalendar2').fullCalendar( 'getDate' ));
   //dayClicked($('#mycalendar2').fullCalendar( 'getDate' ))

        });
```

You might have to use the viewDisplay event. But it gets a bit complicated in there. Here is a document how to use it.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/viewDisplay/

Look at DoomsDay answer- nice solution :D

---

### An internal hack for day click and possibly other buttons.

You can open fullcalendar.js and goto line about... 3220 or search for **Slot/Day clicking and binding**

```
/* Slot/Day clicking and binding
-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/


function dayBind(cells) {
    cells.click(slotClick)
        .mousedown(daySelectionMousedown);

   //OVER HERE INSERT YOUR CUSTOM CALL!
     setMyOtherCalendar();
}
```

and in your page somewhere you would havbe a public function of **setMyOtherCalendar** and it would have this simple code in it.. init mate?

```
function setMyOtherCalendar(){

  $('#mycalendar2').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate',      $('#mycalendar1').fullCalendar( 'getDate' ) );

};
```

Comment: brilliant! One other thing, if I click the today button how do I get the other calendar to 'sync' to that date? I don't know how to hook into that event.

Comment: I edited- but i am not sure how to bind to the today button propery - it think you must use viewDisplay event somehow to call `dayClicked` in there

Comment: Be warned, it IS possible! :-) See my answer

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ppumkin for *dayclick*.

BUT it is still possible to alter actions of **prev,next,today buttons**. I will use this solution for navigating from #mycalendar1 to #mycalendar2:

```
$("#mycalendar1 .fc-button-prev").click(function() {
  $("#mycalendar2").fullCalendar('prev');
});
$("#mycalendar1 .fc-button-next").click(function() {
  $("#mycalendar2").fullCalendar('next');
});
$("#mycalendar1 .fc-button-today").click(function() {
  $("#mycalendar2").fullCalendar('today');
});
```

And keeping ppumkin solution for *dayClick*:

```
dayClick: function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ) {
   $('#mycalendar2').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date );
},
```

You should use **each** keyword if you're using .fullcalendar instead of #mycalendar2 (if you are using more than two calendars).

An example is shown on : http://jsfiddle.net/Doomsday/6P2CR/

Comment: Eemmm.. :D What does this do? It is still pre-binding before the calender finishes is it not? can you make an example cause I cannot see this working well :D

Comment: Nice! Very Nice +1 :D SO needs more ppl like you!