# Dividing days into several sections in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to divide days into sections, for example there are a lot of events in one day, and they take place in different rooms (A, B, C), I want to divide each days into columns A, B, C to separate events from different rooms. There is any way to do this?

Comment: I need to do the exact same thing.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same prerequesites and I will do this way:

In fullcalendar options:

- Create a fullcalendar "control" with title, prev, next and today.
- Create N fullcalendar "events" without navigation, and set each title to each room.

You should apply some tricks to render nice calendars :

- Calendar "control":  hide body **fc-content** (CSS **display:none**)
- Second Calendar and: hide left axis **fc-agenda-axis** (CSS **width: 0px**)

In your data and js handling:

- Fullcalendar "control" must control all others calendars (see [How do I set the date of a calendar view from another view using Jquery FullCalendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031419/how-do-i-set-the-date-of-a-calendar-view-from-another-view-using-jquery-fullcalen/6046319#6046319) )
- Load events from Room A to Calendar A, Room B to Calendar B, etc.

You can start with this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8ZM4x/1/

And then replace events source with yours :

```
$('#mycalendar1').fullCalendar(
            {
                    events: [     
                          ...
                    ]
           });
```

Comment: It would be great if you could post a jsfiddle. Thanks.

Comment: @Doomsday - can you elaborate a little?  I need to do this, too, only I need to divide the day into nine parts (nine rooms).  Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: I placed a feature request with the FullCalendar folks.

Comment: Added a jsfiddle where you can see several fullcalendar and only one controller.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Doomsday.  Can you get it it into, oh, say five columns?  For my needs, I need five columns that will run the vertical length of each day so I can add events to any time in the column.  I'm on the verge of hacking the library myself if I can't figure something out.

Comment: I gave you my +1 for the fiddle.

Comment: Three, five or ten columns, you just need to add more calendars for each column you need. About height, you need to use the official settings without any hacks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fork of the fullCalendar library that will provide this functionality - they call it a *Resource View*.

http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/

Check out my [answer to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093677/resizable-jquery-for-booking-rooms/21286442#21286442) for more information.