# Resizable jQuery for booking rooms

Tags: jquery, calendar, resizable

I'm looking at the resizable jQuery UI element: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#snap-to-grid

I have a grid of booking slots - ie. days of week down the left, and hours of the day across the top - all arranged as individual DIVs into a grid.

What I would like to be able to do is, someone click on an open slot (or hour) to book that time - however, if there is time available before or after the hour clicked on, allow the person to resize their hour booking to the next hour, but not to allow it to overlap an already existing slot on that day.

Does anyone know of any examples that show how to do this?

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: Have you found any answers to this?  I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi - I'm afraid not... Mark

Comment: Well, I'm trying to figure out a solution myself.  There is a fellow on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060204/dividing-days-into-several-sections-in-fullcalendar who wrote a fiddle that will put *two days* into *one day* but it's not quite what we are looking for.  Myself, I am on the verge of hacking the FullCalendar library to see if I can figure something out.  I'll post back here if I remember.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search there are actually a few solutions:

This page is the best you can get on the topic in Stack Overflow: [Adding a Resource View/Gannt chart to jQuery Fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269117/adding-a-resource-view-gannt-chart-to-jquery-fullcalendar)

There are a few fullCalendar forks that include a resource view that will do what you (and I) are looking for:

https://github.com/benbruscella/fullcalendar

https://github.com/ikelin/fullcalendar

*But this one is the most versatile*, I believe, because it will provide a resource view for day, week, and month whereas the other two only provide for the day (at least as per my quick evaluation):

http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/

In fact, here is a list of all the github fullCalendar forks:
http://forked.yannick.io/arshaw/fullcalendar