# jquery fullcalendar plugin show all events with in slotMinutes in a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I have recently used fullcalender plugin for showing events.I have put slot minutes to 60 so that the time intervel has split into one hour.The problem is, the events which happens before 30 mins is showing on first columns and events which is happens after 30 mins is on next columns as follows.
[image]

I want to show all events within one hour in same column.Please help.

Comment: There is a similar question here (without a good solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060204/dividing-days-into-several-sections-in-fullcalendar  I put in a feature request for something like this just today.